# how to use variable php as array index within pg_Query

Tags: php, arrays, postgresql

Hi I got a problem to insert form data using PHP into database. 
I got too many data that has to be input into database. so i use pg_query inside for loop. But the error shown up

*"syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\SchedulingApplication\Code\dosavecapacity.php on line 56"*

Here's my code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 32; $i++) 
 {   
    $eva = pg_query("INSERT INTO FC VALUES('$input','$tipe','$chan','$blnthn','$days[($i)]','$time[1]','$tipe31[($i+1100)]');");    
 }
```

is there any wrong syntax that i've made? How am i supposed to do for using php variable as an array index?

Thankyou in advanced. :D

Comment: please show your form values. what exactly is coming in request ?

Comment: try `$eva = pg_query("INSERT INTO FC VALUES('$input','$tipe','$chan','$blnthn','$days[$i]','$time[1]','$tipe31[$i+1100]');"); `

Comment: @Ranjith Sorry for late response. It stil doesnt work using your way :(

Comment: try removing `;` : `$eva = pg_query("INSERT INTO FC VALUES('$input','$tipe','$chan','$blnthn','$days[$i]','$time[1]','$tipe31[$i+110‌​0]')");`

Comment: @Ranjith Still doesn't work.

Comment: @Shieryn what error is coming and  please show your form values. what exactly is coming in request ?

Comment: @Ranjith Please look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37432748/phpexcel-to-insert-database-using-pg-query